# Bottom of my background inexplicable cut off

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm experiencing a strange cutoff of my background image at the very bottom of my page. It's only evident if you have a short browser window and scroll to the very bottom. And it only happens on longer pages.

Firebug inspection reveals a viewport-width element, stretching entirely across the browser window at the very bottom, about 50px high that seems to be "blocking" it, but this doesn't correspond to any div in my layout - that I can find, anyway!

Also, when rolling over this strange element, it's the first `<HTML lang="en-us">` line that gets highlighted in Firebug.

Longer page: http://bit.ly/151TFnW

============FOLLOWUP==================

Following the helpful suggestions here, I fixed the above by removing the 100% height from the BODY style. But that breaks something else! Now, on this shorter page:

Short page: http://bit.ly/1fvbnHY

The background image is still cut off at the bottom, when the browser window is tall enough to show this.

Remove the 100% on BODY and that second, shorter page is fine - full bg image and bottom margin - BUT the earlier link's problems return.

Help....!!!

Comment: I'm baffled too. This seems to be happening without any supporting HTML. Mysterious indeed.

Comment: Well, this may not technically be addressing the specific issue, but I did solve it sufficiently for the time being. I revised the css of the div holding the background image (the tree), changing "height=100%" to "height=2000px" (larger than the height of the image). (I had noticed as well that the gradient bottom of the tree was actually getting cut off.) 

Now it appears beautifully. The drawback is, it adds scrollbars even when the rest of the page is completely visible. So, still not quite "solved" but "solved enough"...

Comment: Don't suppose you can post a version without the arbitrary 2000px height somewhere, or create a jsFiddle with just the important parts?

Comment: Hi Tieson! I've made some changes to the CSS, going back to just a 100% height, not a fixed 2000 pixels - the spurious scrollbars did not fly with my client, as I suspected they wouldn't. The bit.ly link above will take you to the same page as it stands currently. That dark green gap is bigger than ever...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks to be caused by the `height` value assigned to `body`. When I remove that rule, most of the gap goes away. I assume the last bit is from some of the margin from the footer spilling over.

Comment: Thanks, doing that does seem to fix it! Alas, there's an issue where they were seeing a tiny, tiny sliver of a slightly different colour at the bottom of their gigantic monitor - an issue I can't even see on my (large but not as large as theirs) screen, so I had to do a screen-sharing session today with them to try and solve that. I did... and part of the solution was to add 100% height to `html`. I've left that in and hope that the problem isn't back tomorrow. If not, we're good. Regardless, THANK YOU so much Tieson for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @AdamAbrams If you have a version of the background that is just the tree (with a transparent background), you could make the body background either a solid green color or use CSS3 to recreate the gradient. You could then load the tree into another layer that fills the viewport. CSS3 also lets you have multiple background images, though I haven't had a need so far to test browser support for those rules.

Comment: Thanks Tieson for the suggestion, but I'm loath to re-open the can of worms of redoing the site layout now - I'm on the brink of wrapping up what has been a very finicky project already in many other ways so hoping that's not needed. I'm going to post a followup vs. a comment as the problem has evolved somewhat...

Comment: Actually I edited my original post to describe what's happening now, I'm rapidly going insane...  8^)

Comment: Further info if it's helpful: the BODY is not going to 100% height despite my CSS rule. I've added a red 1px border on the BODY to show this - on the "shorter" pages like: http://bit.ly/1fvbnHY , it stops quite a bit short of the bottom for no apparent reason. On all the other pages, it's OK...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may or may not be considered a proper fix, as it doesn't address the reason why the pages in question reacted differently to the "body at 100% height" setting than the rest of the site... but I solved it by targeting it with CSS so that the problem pages simply don't receive that CSS rule.

So, sigh of relief, but tinged with the knowledge that I didn't really figure out why it was doing what it was doing.

Comment: To be specific, I added conditional code to the WordPress theme's header so that the HTML tag had "class=heightfix" applied to it on just the affected pages; then in my CSS, I only gave html.heightfix the 100% height. Solved!